# crossing number and thickness of a simple graph $G$

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

> **Crossing number$($cr$)$**: The crossing number of a simple graph is the minimum number of crossings that can occur when this graph is drawn in the plane where no three arcs representing edges are permitted to cross at the same point. For an undirected simple graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $e$ edges such that $e > 7n$ the crossing number is always at least $$cr(G)\geq \frac{e^3}{29n^2}$$

$(1)$ I was wondering is there exist any upper bound in general$?$ [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_(graph_theory)#Special_cases) is a upper bound for the crossing number of the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$. I need a proof of that result.$($if possible than provide a simple's one$)$

> **Thickness**: The thickness of a simple graph G is the smallest number of
>   planar subgraphs of G that have G as their union.

$(2)$ I was wondering is there any relation between these two number$?$

Comment: +1. A great question! ********** Are edges represented in the plane as topological arcs or as Euclidean intervals? This is about both notions. Thus the main (by far) viariant would be A-A, then the second (the second main by far) would be E-E.

Comment: Terminology "thickness" is poor (for logical reasons and due to the other uses of "thickness" in mathematics. I'd call it "the layer number".

Comment: I'd encourage you to post this question on MO (with a reference to SE).

Comment: Hm, "the layer number" name would be a bit mathematically imprecise (but "thickness" is even much worse). It's hard to come up with a name that would represent the given notion adequately. ######### I think, I have it! The "Deplane number", there is even a tinge of humor to it.

Comment: Sorry to late response @WlodAA . I haven't access to internet for a while. In your $3$rd comment you said MO. I didn't get that. Did you mean Mathematics Meta$?$

Comment: MO = MathOverflow (a part of the SE network).

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the party, but here we go. (i) Clearly, as the addition of edges does not decrease the number of crossings, the graph on $n$ nodes with the highest crossing number is $K_n$. The current upper bound can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_(graph_theory)).
(ii) The [cube connected cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube-connected_cycles) are degree three graphs (hence they have thickness two) but they have non-constant crossing number, hence there is no clear relation.